# Invalid credential error on trying to send a sms via smpp server from php code

Tags: php, smpp

We have a smpp server for which we have

1. ip address
2. username
3. password
4. port no

on entering these details to code and trying to send a sms we are recieving the below error message:-

> Bind Transmitter PDU: 0 100 101 109 111 49 50 51 0 97 99 116 105 118
>   101 0 51 0 0 0 Sending PDU, len == 36 Sending PDU, header-len == 16
>   Sending PDU, command_id == 2 Trying to read PDU. Reading PDU : 16
>   bytes. Stream len : 12 Command id : 2. Command status : 13.
>   sequence_number : 1. Got CM_BIND_TRANSMITTER_RESP.  Warning: unpack()
>   [function.unpack]: Type a: not enough input, need 1, have 0 in
>   /home/acftp052/public_html/smpp/smppclass.php on line 580 system id :
>   . Received PDU: €(0)(0)(2)(0)(0)(0)(13)(0)(0)(0)(1) Error binding to
>   SMPP server. Invalid credentials? Sending PDU, len == 16 Sending PDU,
>   header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 21 Trying to read PDU.
>   Socket was closed.!! Connection lost. In split_message. One message:
>   30 PDU spec: a1cca1cca14ccca1a1ccccca30. Sending PDU, len == 76
>   Sending PDU, header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 4 Trying to
>   read PDU. Socket was closed.!! Connection lost. Sending PDU, len == 16
>   Sending PDU, header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 6 Trying to
>   read PDU. Socket was closed.!! Connection lost.

We are able to deduce from the error that the credential provided is wrong.

My Doubt is:-

1. What details are required to connect to a smpp server.
2. should the code files be deployed on Smpp server or can it be deployed to a different server and try to access the smpp server to send the message.(We did try to connect to the smpp server via filezilla but it was unsuccessful)
3. is from number manadatory when we are trying to send a message from system to a mobile.

Please guide us. We are stuck with this problem since a week done all the research that i know off but i am turning only towards dead end and going blank.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks & Regards
Krishnan.

Comment: Can you share the code that creates the SMPP session with SMSC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answers are based on .[SMPP 3.4 spec](http://www.smsforum.net/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.zip)

===

I am assuming that your setup looks like this:

1. You are developing SMPP client (a.k.a. ESME).
2. You have connectivity information to a SMPP server (a.k.a. SMSC).

***Question 1: What details are required to connect to a smpp server.***

At bare minimum, a ESME needs the following to connect to a SMSC (required at TCP level):

1. IP of SMSC
2. Port of SMSC

Most SMSC will also require (but this is not mandatory):

1. system_id (serves as username)
2. password

Some SMSC will also require:

1. system_type (see section 4.1.1 in SMPP 3.4 spec)
2. address_range (see section 4.1.1 in SMPP 3.4 spec)

***Question 2: should the code files be deployed on Smpp server or can it be deployed to a different server and try to access the smpp server to send the message.(We did try to connect to the smpp server via filezilla but it was unsuccessful)***

SMSC (i.e. SMPP server) and ESME (i.e. SMPP client) are not required to be on the same box; you can do if you want. Only requirement is that they can connect over TCP.

I believe FileZilla is a FTP client and it has got nothing to do with SMSC.

***Question 3: is from number manadatory when we are trying to send a message from system to a mobile.***

I am assuming that you are using SUBMIT_SM to send a message (since you are trying to connect via BIND_TRANSMITTER).

In the spec, the **from number** is referred as **source_addr** (see section 4.4.1/5.2.8 in SMPP 3.4 spec). Most SMSC will require **source_addr** however it is not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Wahid Sadik. It was helpfull. and sorry for the delayed response i am still having the same issue i will post about it soon hope you can help us out.